# Why is unshadowing needed?

Tags: passwords

```
john /etc/shadow
```

look like working, because john will use many-many CPU for it. But why is unshadowing needed? Why isn't it enough to use "john /etc/shadow"? Because of the salting? Can someone explain why is unshadowing needed?

UPDATE: the unshadowing looks like this:

```
unshadow /etc/passwd /etc/shadow > /tmp/unshadowed
john /tmp/unshadowed
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John will also use the information from the GECOS fields in `/etc/passwd` as dictionary words used to crack the hash.

Answer (score 7):

The unshadow utility combines the password hash stored in the /etc/shadow file with the contents of the /etc/passwd file. When the two files are combined, you can then crack users belonging to specific groups or skip users with expired credentials etc. For example, an expired file with have the shell=/etc/expired in /etc/passwd file, you can tell john to skip all those hashes which have a shell=/etc/expired option set:
`john --shells=-/etc/expired <path of unshadow password file>`

Note a minus sign infront of the shells parameter. If tell john to skip those hashes having the expired shell.

`john --groups=admin,root <path of the unshadow password file>`

The above command is going to crack only those accounts which are in the admin and root group. Hence when the two files are combined, you have a lot of flexibility which hashes you want to crack. But you can certainly use john just with the shadow file as well if you want to.

Comment: So it's only for this reason? isn't it needed for salting, or other purposes?

Comment: @gaskopeter salt of the password is stored in the /etc/shadow file with the hash. You don't need /etc/passwd file for the salt because /etc/passwd don't have any salt.

Comment: The weak point in most systems is the users, so you might have wordlists that are tailored to users in a particular role, or career, by using a groups filter you could do more targeted cracking attempts.

Answer (score 3):

John was written at a time before /etc/shadow was common.  Old /etc/passwd files stood alone, and contained the password information now found in /etc/shadow in more modern UNIX/Linux implementations.  unshadow recombines the two files, recreating the older style of /etc/passwd file which is what John eats.